# How will i split the columns in a text file using NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a excel file that has 2000 columns, my requirement is to extract specific subsets of columns from this excel file and send them to various different files like below example

**Column A,B go to one file**

**Column A,C go to the second file**

**Column A,D go to the third file**

**Column A,E go to the third file....**

How will i achieve this using NiFi?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Easy" way will be to do a custom script, with Jython for example
Another, way will be to parse the header --> split each columns name into flowfiles (so n columns names = n flowfiles) --> do a query record with parameter

Answer (score 0):

If is .xlsx use the ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor to conver the .xlsx and send it to PartitionRecord that has this kind of setup:

you need to setup a CSVReader / Writer (default settings - inferschema) and enable them.

- you can have multi cols setup like you see bellow (also see the doco on recordpaths !)
- then you can have a routeon attribute to route the output flows to where you want to do more processing on them or merge and put into files.

[image]
See more about recordpaths here https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#structure

Yes in your case you have 2000 columns OK !
The attributes don`t have to hardcode the mapping for the column , the attribures support expression language (they can be derived)

- no such thing as ready to use solution on Stackoverflow.

I've stopped for a while posting on Stackoverflow becouse of this! come squazze that brain

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in this case i need to hard core all the 6k columns?

Comment: well i gave you the proc to used for this ! i am not gonna build the proc as well !